# What is the distinction between @connection and keyArgs?

Tags: apollo, apollo-client

Apollo 3 introduced typePolicies and [keyArgs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-field-behavior/#specifying-key-arguments) as a way to tell the cache how to store data and avoid duplicate entries. This seems akin to the [@connection](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/advanced-topics/#the-connection-directive) directive, which provides similar functionality (specify a custom store key for results).

Is it necessary and safe to use both in an application? When would it make sense to choose one over the other?

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same question. After 3 days of searching and reading,
I found a link to a gist that answer the question. [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/benjamn/f4436977bfc834fd15779ac5c4ff11c9#gistcomment-2944103)

Comment: Seems a little out of date though. This looks like some initial planning discussion for the feature. I'd like to find some official docs about it.